# XSLT Need to Limit Return of Multiple Instances in XML File to 18 Characters

Tags: xslt, concatenation, substring

I currently have the following code to combine multiple instances of Ustrd into one returned value:

```
<Ustrd>
    <xsl:value-of select="a:RmtInf/a:Ustrd"/>
</Ustrd>
```

This returns:

```
<Ustrd>Item-1 Item-2 Item-3</Ustrd>
```

The problem is that I need to limit this to 18 characters, and the substring function does not work with a sequence of items.

Tried:

```
<Ustrd>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(a:RmtInf/a:Ustrd, 1, 18"/>
</Ustrd>
```

Expected Result:

```
<Ustrd>Item-1 Item-2 Item</Ustrd>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string-join` first e.g. `substring(string-join(a:RmtInf/a:Ustrd, ' '), 1, 18)`. In XPath 3.1 you can also write that as `a:RmtInf/a:Ustrd => string-join(' ') => substring(1, 18)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way this could be done in XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Ustrd>
        <xsl:variable name="temp">
          <xsl:for-each select="RmtInf/Ustrd">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
              <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($temp,1,18)"/>
    </Ustrd>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Only need to add your namespace.)

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgzCL4

Comment: If `<xsl:value-of select="a:RmtInf/a:Ustrd"/>` outputs `<Ustrd>Item-1 Item-2 Item-3</Ustrd>` and `substring` on `a:RmtInf/a:Ustrd` doesn't work then the poster must be using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.